# Finding second highest record from a table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to find salary and the employees name from employee table.This employee table have column like emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary. To be clear:

```
 emplyee
   --------------
   | emp_id|emp_name|emp_salary|
   -----------------------------
   | 100   |John    | 2500     |
   | 200   |Nash    | 1500     |
   | 300   |Koffe   | 100      |
   | 400   |Anan    | 6000     |
   | 500   |Moon    | 2600     |
   -----------------------------
```

From the above table second highest salary is 2600. How can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

SELECT max(salary)
FROM emptable
WHERE salary < (SELECT max(salary)
                FROM emptable);

Answer (score 0):

### we can achieve this one in correlated sub query

select e1.emp_ename,e1.emp_salary from employee e1
where 2=(select count(distinct e2.emp_salary) from employee e2 where e2.salary>=e2.salary);

### see how it works

select * from employees
emp_id     emp_ename       emp_salary
1           naresh           100
2           suresh           150
3           mahesh           200
4           sai              250
 in the above table second highest salary is 200
correlated sub query means first parent query is executed first then child query is executed

### see how this query is working

select e1.emp_ename,e1.emp_salary from employee e1
where 2=(select count(distinct e2.emp_salary) from employee e2 where e2.salary>=e2.salary);

1st step:   first row sal  goes to child query where clause

select e1.emp_ename,e1.emp_salary from employee e1
where 2=(select count(distinct e2.emp_salary) from employee e2 where e2.salary>=100)
so it counts how rows greater than 100(i.e=4)
so condition false
select e1.emp_ename,e1.emp_salary from employee e1
where 2=4(false)

### 2nd step

select e1.emp_ename,e1.emp_salary from employee e1
where 2=(select count(distinct e2.emp_salary) from employee e2 where e2.salary>=150);

select e1.emp_ename,e1.emp_salary from employee e1
where 2=3(FALSE)

### 3r step

select e1.emp_ename,e1.emp_salary from employee e1
where 2=(select count(distinct e2.emp_salary) from employee e2 where e2.salary>=200);

select e1.emp_ename,e1.emp_salary from employee e1
where 2=2(TRUE)

SO FINAL WE GOT 200
 I HOPE IT WELL USE FULL FOR YOU ALL THE BEST